# Disable button in jsp depending on the method return

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have method which checking DB if user is applied to course
if he has already applied, then the button is disabled

Method which checking isStudentApplied to Course

```
public static boolean isStudentRegisteredToCourse(Student student, CourseDTO course){
        String query = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT student_of_course.student_id, student_of_course.course_id FROM student_of_course WHERE student_of_course.student_id = ? AND student_of_course.course_id=?);";
        ResultSet rs;
        int result;
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, student.getId());
            preparedStatement.setInt(2,course.getId());
            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()){
                result=rs.getInt(1);
                if(result==1)
                    return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Servlet Method which working with sessions

```
public class CourseServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                          javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if("register".equals(action)){
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            Account account = (Account)session.getAttribute("loguser");
            CourseDTO courseDTO = (CourseDTO) session.getAttribute("courseDTO");
            Student student = AccountDAO.getStudentByAccountId(account);
            CourseDAO.setCourseForUser(student,courseDTO);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/course.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

jsp

```
<form  action="course" method="post">
    <dl>
        <dt>progress</dt>
        <dd>${courseDTO.progress}</dd>
        <dt>theme</dt>
        <dd>${courseDTO.theme_name}</dd>
        <dt>description</dt>
        <dd>${courseDTO.description}</dd>
        <dt>teacherName</dt>
        <dd>${courseDTO.teacherName}</dd>
        <dt>duration</dt>
        <dd>${courseDTO.duration}</dd>
        <dt>quantity</dt>
        <dd>${courseDTO.quantity}</dd>
    <dd><button name="action" value="register">Register</button></dd>
</dl>
</form>
```

so i wanna check is user applied to course, if he is, then `<button name="action" value="register">Register</button>` becomes `disabled`
How it possible to do?

Comment: Hi ,how that method gets called ?